# Как словари с одинаковым значением одного ключа собрать в отдельные списки

Tags: python, словари, dict

Есть список словарей:

```
a = [{'letter': 'q', 'count': 2}, 
{'letter': 'r', 'count': 3}, 
{'letter': 'q', 'count': 5}, 
{'letter': 'e', 'count': 1}, 
{'letter': 'q', 'count': 6}, 
{'letter': 'r', 'count': 2}]
```

Необходимо сгруппировать их так, чтобы получить список словарей с одинаковым значением ключа letter, то есть

```
a = [[{'letter': 'q', 'count': 2}, {'letter': 'q', 'count': 5}, {'letter': 'q', 'count': 6}], [{'letter': 'r', 'count': 3}, {'letter': 'r', 'count': 2}], [{'letter': 'e', 'count': 1}]
```

Использовала такой код, но получается что есть несколько списков с одинаковыми словарями

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    letter = a[i]['letter']
    sp = []
    sp.append(a[i])
    for j in range(1, len(a)):
        if a[j]['letter'] == letter:
            sp.append(a[j])
```

Comment: А что это за примеры такие? Список словарей "a", но в коде никакого "а" нет.  Зато есть загадочный detection да еще и с индексом ['name']?  А имя переменной "letter" дублирует ключ. Это все что-бы всех запутать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще пересобрать данные в словарь с подходящим ключом:

```py
a = [{'letter': 'q', 'count': 2}, 
{'letter': 'r', 'count': 3}, 
{'letter': 'q', 'count': 5}, 
{'letter': 'e', 'count': 1}, 
{'letter': 'q', 'count': 6}, 
{'letter': 'r', 'count': 2}]

sp = {}
for i in a:
    letter = i['letter']
    sp[letter] = sp.get(letter, []) + [i]

a = list(sp.values())
print(*a, sep='\n')
```

Вывод:

```
[{'letter': 'q', 'count': 2}, {'letter': 'q', 'count': 5}, {'letter': 'q', 'count': 6}]
[{'letter': 'r', 'count': 3}, {'letter': 'r', 'count': 2}]
[{'letter': 'e', 'count': 1}]
```